# How to get values from JQuery - IonRangeSlider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

how can I get low and high values from [ion.rangeSlider](http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/en.html) component by clicking a button?

This is my jQuery code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#range_1").ionRangeSlider({
            min: 10,
            max: 50,
            from: 10,
            to: 20,
            type: 'double',
            step: 1,
            prettify: true,
            hasGrid: false
        });
    });
</script>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#get_values').click(function(){
            var low = $('#range_1').... ???;
            var high = $('#range_1').... ???;
            alert(low);
        });
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

here is a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/IonDen/xaaw56bk/

```
var $range = $(".js-range-slider"),
    $result = $(".js-result"),
    $getvalues = $(".js-get-values"),

    from = 0,
    to = 0;

var saveResult = function (data) {
    from = data.fromNumber;
    to = data.toNumber;
};

var writeResult = function () {
    var result = "from: " + from + ", to: " + to;
    $result.html(result);
};

$range.ionRangeSlider({
    type: "double",
    min: 10,
    max: 50,
    from: from,
    to: to,
    onLoad: function (data) {
        saveResult(data);
        writeResult();
    },
    onChange: saveResult,
    onFinish: saveResult
});

$getvalues.on("click", writeResult);
```

Comment: This example is outdated.

Comment: The correct values in the saveResult function: data.from and data.to

Answer (score 24):

```js
// Launch plugin
$("#range").ionRangeSlider({
    type: "double",
    min: 0,
    max: 1000,
    from: 200,
    to: 500
});

// Saving it's instance to var
var slider = $("#range").data("ionRangeSlider");

// Get values
var from = slider.result.from;
var to = slider.result.to;
```

See solution at http://jsfiddle.net/2qLum6s7/. Works with latest version of Ion.RangeSlider (2.1.2).

Comment: @scahill Thank you it helped me very much

Answer (score 11):

Use jQuery's data() method:

```
var low = $('#range_1').data().from;
var high = $('#range_1').data().to;
```

Comment: Jip, The most shortest, bestest answer for me. I also got down to this whilst debugging, but since you gave this as an answer, +1

Answer (score 8):

Previous answer was based on old plugin API and don't work any more. Here is the new one, for 2.x version:
http://jsfiddle.net/IonDen/2L15xoym/

```
var $range = $(".js-range-slider"),
    $result = $(".js-result"),
    $getvalues = $(".js-get-values"),

    from = 0,
    to = 0;

var saveResult = function (data) {
    from = data.from;
    to = data.to;
};

var writeResult = function () {
    var result = "from: " + from + ", to: " + to;
    $result.html(result);
};

$range.ionRangeSlider({
    type: "double",
    min: 10,
    max: 50,
    from: from,
    to: to,
    onStart: function (data) {
        saveResult(data);
        writeResult();
    },
    onChange: saveResult,
    onFinish: saveResult
});

$getvalues.on("click", writeResult);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
const range = $('#range_1');

const rangeData = range.data('ionRangeSlider');
const start = rangeData.result.from;
const max = rangeData.result.max;
// rangeData.result['property']
```

**Version 2.3.0 (Tested)**

Answer (score 1):

This method works on the latest version. Use event onChange to get data from attributes "from" and "to".
Ion.RangeSlider v2.3.1:

```
    var slider = $('.js-range-slider');

    slider.ionRangeSlider({
        type: "double",
        prefix: '$',
        grid: true,
    });


    slider.on("change", function () {
        var $inp = $(this);
        var from = $inp.data("from");   // get data from attribute
        var to = $inp.data("to");       // get data from attribute

        console.log(from, to);          
});
```

Html Markup:

```
<input type="text" class="js-range-slider" name="my_range" value="" data-min="100" data-max="4000" data-from="1000" data-to="2000"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var val = $('#theSpecificSliderID').slider('value'); // Get value <br>
$('#theSpecificSliderID').slider('value', 33); // Set value
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the start, change or finish overload. I'm using finish overload and update the value to SomeValue element.

```
   $("#Range_1").ionRangeSlider({
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        type: 'single',
        step: 1,
        postfix: " %",
        prettify: false,
        hasGrid: true,
        onFinish: function(data){
            var value = data.fromNumber;
            $("#SomeValue").val(value);
        }
    });
```