# Ion.RangeSlider. Problem with parsing a value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have JS-Range Slider. I need to get min and max values from input, but I get an error in console when I I move the slider: The specified value "1000;2327" cannot be parsed, or is out of range." and etc

```
<input type="number" class="js-range-slider" name="my_range" value="" data-min="100" data-max="4000" data-from="1000" data-to="2000" data-grid="true" />
```

Why is it happening?

```
$(".js-range-slider").ionRangeSlider({
    type: "double",
    prefix: '$',
    min: 100,
    max: 4000,
    from: 1000,
    to: 2000,
    values: [75, 300000]
});



$(".filter-btn_send").click(function () {
    var min = $(".js-range-slider").slider("option", "min");
    var max = $(".js-range-slider").slider("option", "max");

    console.log("min: " + min + " max: " + max);
});
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where in the code do you get this problem? In the console.log or in some event?

Comment: In console.log()

Comment: I don't know what to do in this case, some problem with parsing...

Comment: @riffnl l posted a screenshot where the problem appears immediately after opening the page.

Comment: I added "some kind of answer", also take a look at the other solutions I added in the edit

Answer (score 1):

Two things wrong with the approach you're using;

1 - you're resetting the slider as a slider again in the event
and

2 - you're not actually "getting" that value.

Best option (for what I can see now) is to change the values you want to use (send or something) from the onChange function.
Like so:

```
let minVal;
let maxVal;
$(".js-range-slider").ionRangeSlider({   
  type: "double",
  prefix: '$',
  min: 100,
  max: 4000,
  from: 1000,
  to: 2000,
  values: [75, 300000],
  onChange: function (data) {
    minVal = data.from;
    maxVal = data.to;
  }
});
```

Above is untested, but it should be something along those lines.
Second (coming back to the first comment) - you "re-assign" the slider, when you initialise the slider it should be something like this:

```
let slider = $(".js-range-slider").ionRangeSlider({ // etc
```

and after that (if possible) you could use that "slider" as container for your values, like:

```
let maxVal = slider.to;
```

EDIT: Also take a look here: [How to get values from JQuery - IonRangeSlider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26641024/how-to-get-values-from-jquery-ionrangeslider) (possible duplicate)

Comment: let slider = $(".js-range-slider").ionRangeSlider() ? Why, If I have maxVal and minVal, and Event: onchange(). I get values these variables, but I get these messages.

Comment: I didn't quite understand why need to define same ioRangeSlider like before:
**`let slider = $(".js-range-slider").ionRangeSlider({
  type: "double",
  prefix: '$',
  min: 100,
  max: 4000,
  from: 1000,
  to: 2000,
  values: [75, 300000],
  onChange: function (data) {
    minVal = data.from;
    maxVal = data.to;
}`**

Comment: You don't need to "redo" or "redefine" your slider - this is just like the initial slider but with a variable attached to it

Comment: I'll look at topic, which you submitted me

Comment: For some reason, none of the solutions work for me on the latest version: v 2.3.1

Comment: https://ibb.co/Nr5cZSg 
This solution must be work...But no

Comment: `$(".js-range-slider").ionRangeSlider({
        type: "double",
        prefix: '$',
        min: 100,
        max: 4000,
        from: 1000,
        to: 2000,
    });

    const rangeData = $(".js-range-slider").data('ionRangeSlider');
    const start = rangeData.result.from;
    const max = rangeData.result.max;` Didn't work

Comment: Or so     
   `const range = $('.js-range-slider');
    const rangeData = range.data('ionRangeSlider');
    const start = rangeData.result.from;
    const max = rangeData.result.max;`

Comment: `let start;
    let max;
    let slider = $(".js-range-slider").ionRangeSlider({
        type: "double",
        prefix: '$',
        min: 100,
        max: 4000,
        from: 1000,
        to: 2000,
        values: [0, 032032],
        onChange: function (data) {
            start = data.from;
            max = data.to;
        }
    });

    max = slider.to; also
    console.log(start, max);` also

Answer (score 0):

Solved on version Ion.RangeSlider v2.3.1:

```
    var slider = $('.js-range-slider');

    slider.ionRangeSlider({
        type: "double",
        prefix: '$',
        grid: true,
    });


    slider.on("change", function () {
        var $inp = $(this);
        var from = $inp.data("from");   // get data from attribute
        var to = $inp.data("to");       // get data from attribute

        console.log(from, to);          
});
```

Html Markup:

```
<input type="text" class="js-range-slider" name="my_range" value="" data-min="100" data-max="4000" data-from="1000" data-to="2000"/>
```